# Is there an annotation that denotes a max Android API version?

Tags: android, android-appcompat, androidx, backwards-compatibility, android-annotations

The annotation `@RequiresApi` is helpful for requiring that the annotated element is only called on the given API level or higher. However, there does not appear to be a corresponding annotation for requiring that the annotated element is only called on the given API or lower.

For example, given something like:

```kotlin
@RequiresMaxApi(28) // or @DeprecatedSinceAndroid(29)
fun doSomethingWithExternalStorage() {
    val dir = Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory() // This is deprecated in API 29
    // ...
}
```

Calling `doSomethingWithExternalStorage()` from code that does not include a check like:

```kotlin
if (VERSION.SDK_INT < 29) {
    doSomethingWithExternalStorage()
}
```

Without the above API check, `doSomethingWithExternalStorage()` would display a lint error/warning, similar to how `@RequiresApi` does.

From my understanding, this is also similar to how `@DeprecatedSinceKotlin` works.

Is there an existing annotation that meets these requirements, or is there another way to achieve the desired result?

Comment: You should already be getting a deprecation indicator (strikethrough) if your `compileSdkVersion` is 29 or higher. And I think that there is a compiler flag that you can set to fail builds on deprecation warnings.

Comment: @CommonsWare That's not what I want though. Just because something's deprecated, doesn't mean that wasn't the correct (or possibly only) way to do something on previous API versions. I want to be able to scope code with an annotation that prevents it from being used on API X and later until the `minSdkVersion` is bumped high enough to remove the code entirely.

Comment: hmmmm what about [create it](https://engineering.wework.com/custom-annotations-in-android-af43514f2f1b) :)

Comment: I created a followup qustion for this regarding desugar-lib-version: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/77721406/is-there-an-android-annotation-requiresapi-xxx-or-desugared-library-version

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
@androidx.annotation.DeprecatedSinceApi(29)
fun doSomethingWithExternalStorage() {
    val dir = Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory() // This is deprecated in API 29
    // ...
}
```

From [androidx-annotation-DeprecatedSinceApi-docs](https://developer.android.com/reference/androidx/annotation/DeprecatedSinceApi) :

> Denotes that this API is only useful until the given API level; after that, a more suitable platform API is available.