# Is there an Android annotation (@RequiresApi >= xxx or desugared-library-version >= y.z)?

Tags: android, android-appcompat, androidx, backwards-compatibility, android-annotations

This is a follow-up-question to [Is there an annotation that denotes a max Android API version?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/64163852/is-there-an-annotation-that-denotes-a-max-android-api-version)

Is there an Android annotation that produces a compiler error if neither [`@RequiresApi(xxx)`](https://developer.android.com/reference/androidx/annotation/RequiresApi)
nor [`@RequireCoreLibraryDesugaring("y.z")`](https://developer.android.com/studio/write/java8-support#library-desugaring) are met?

There is already an annotation [`@RequiresApi(xxx)`](https://developer.android.com/reference/androidx/annotation/RequiresApi) that make the compile fail if minsdk is below xxx.

Since Android introduced [library desugaring](https://developer.android.com/studio/write/java8-support#library-desugaring)
you can use methods that do not meet the `@RequiresApi(xxx)` if you add desugaring to you app, because `desugar_jdk_libs` adds the missing code, if necessary.

Under [`androidx.annotation`](https://developer.android.com/reference/androidx/annotation/package-summary.html) I found nothing that meets my requirements